# AWS RDS Postgres - Retry failed Query automatically after reconnecting/failover

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-rds, hikaricp, failover

I currently have an Aws Rds Postgres multi AZ(13.4) database and multiple Java(Spring + hibernate) Applications that use the database with:

```
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>42.2.24</version>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.7.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I configured HikariCP like this:

```
    public DataSource hikariDataSource() {
        // Adjusting Cache since RDS failover can/will result in a different IP for the Database
        java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "1");
        java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl", "3");

       ....
       final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcURL);
        config.setUsername(user);
        config.setPassword(password);

        // Initial Connect wait time
        config.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
        // "We strongly recommend setting this value, and it should be several seconds shorter than any database or
        // infrastructure imposed connection time limit."
        config.setMaxLifetime(50000);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("socketTimeout", "60");
        // This value must be less than the maxLifetime value
        config.setKeepaliveTime(30000);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(6);
        config.setMinimumIdle(2);
        config.setIdleTimeout(45000);

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
```

When I trigger a failover of the AWS multi AZ Database HikariCP will acknowledge that the connection is lost and after a while reconnect. So far so good. If my Application was in the middle of a Query while the failover occurred, the Application will throw an error because the Connection was lost, something like:

```
2022-06-21 10:45:10 WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7ca90935 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value. 
2022-06-21 10:45:10 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7ca90935: (connection is dead) 
2022-06-21 10:45:10 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7f52ac10 
2022-06-21 10:45:20 WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@24118275 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0) 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:349)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
...
```

and

```
2022-06-21 10:45:20 DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@24118275: (connection is broken) 
2022-06-21 10:45:20 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006 
2022-06-21 10:45:20 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend. 
2022-06-21 10:45:20 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@314419c8<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@320236451 wrapping org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@af06e> 
2022-06-21 10:45:20 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext - HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries 
2022-06-21 10:45:20 ERROR org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by rollback exception 
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
...
```

Now I want to get rid of these errors.
In Mongodb there are Retryable Reads/Writes which wait for a new Primary to be elected, before retrying a query once. Is there something similar I can do with Postgres? I already tried doing a Multi-Az Cluster Setup, but even then the connection is simply lost, error thrown and reestablished.